# How to make the cellphone's screen show the alarm when it is locked

Tags: java, android

I'm learning about AlarmManager; making a simple alarm app. At the moment it's working, but only when the cellphone is unlocked. When I've used an alarm app, the alarm doesn't unlock the cellphone but it is shown on the screen although the cellphone is locked. How can I do this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED flag, like this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Here is the documentation on this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED